# Time delay issue when loading a view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I used many properties as Textfield, labels, Textviews, Uiviews, Tableview, scrollview in employer_REG_NEW Viewcontroller. Now when I call push viewcontroller it takes upto 3 seconds to load the new viewcontroller

My code is

```
employer_REG_NEW *empSIGHN_UPVC = [[employer_REG_NEW alloc] initWithNibName:@"employer_REG_NEW" bundle:nil];
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:empSIGHN_UPVC animated:NO];
```

Comment: Have you called any web service or any heavy task in ViewWillAppear?

Comment: You shold propably read something about Code conventions and such. Your class and variable names are not up to standards.

Comment: Yeah I customise the properties in ViewWillAppear @RonakChaniyara

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are not doing any heavy processing in
viewDidLoad: , viewWillAppear: and viewDidAppear: methods which may overload the main thread.

Comment: Yeah i created a new method and called that in view did load but still facing same issue is there a alternate to load the ui customised properties rather than view didload and view will appear

Comment: Could edit your question and paste the code. If the code you wrote is doing expensive calculations than dispatch it asynchronously on a new queue.